# Objective-C macro type

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I have the following macro:

```
#define MReachabilityReachable (((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).reachableAzureMobileServices);
```

The follwing works fine.

```
BOOL internetReachable = MReachabilityReachable;
if (internetReachable){
    // do someting
}
```

Is there a way to change it to:

```
if (MReachabilityReachable){
   // do something
}
```

The compiler doesn't accept the second snippet.

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: /Users/.../Documents/Developer/....../LoginViewController.m:208:33: Expected expression   it points at the M of MReachabilityReachable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros work by expanding the expression directly as you have written it. In your case, your problem is probably the `;` at the end of your macro.

Let's show this on a simpler macro

```
#define MReachabilityReachable ([appDelegate isReachable]);
```

then

```
BOOL internetReachable = MReachabilityReachable;
```

is expanded to

```
BOOL internetReachable = ([appDelegate isReachable]);;
```

which works but

```
if (MReachabilityReachable) {
```

is expanded to

```
if (([appDelegate isReachable]);) {
```

where the `;` makes the expression invalid.

Comment: wow, that was simple, been working using my workaround  for the past year. Thanks